# Using SendKeys in ExcelVBA - is there a line of code I can use to ensure that the workbook is the top window?

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

In order for sendkeys to work everytime, the workbook that needs the keystrokes must be the top window (I think?). Is there a line I could use that brings the workbook to the top?

I've tried:

```
Thisworkbook.Activate
Windows("This Workbook.xlsm").Activate
```

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. I wouldn't recommend using Sendkeys. **Question:**  Why are you using sendkeys? What are you trying to achieve? On the other hand to bring a window on top, use the API [SetWindowPos](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/SetWindowPos.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

When using SendKeys, you can specify the sheet/cell etc. in your code, such as:

```
    Sub showList()
        Sheet3.Activate        
        Sheet3.Range("L3").Select
        SendKeys "%{down}"
    End Sub
```

Comment: will that work if the excel windows are behind a bunch of other windows (like browsers, file explorers, etc)?

Comment: If they are 'behind' lots of other windows, how do you trigger the code?  If the code is in a module in the workbook you are wanting to apply the SendKeys action, then it should work without any problems.

Comment: Its part of a loop that runs over and over again in the background over several hours.

Comment: As long as you specify the Excel workbook/worksheet in your code, then it shouldn't be aa problem.  Try it and see.